# SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN(array) - H2 Database

Tags: sql, arrays, select, h2

We are trying to select all rows from a table where a specific field has a value that is contained inside an array of values - e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN(array)
```

The specific use is seeing if the field contains a specific User Group from an array of provided User Groups that the user currently belongs to - e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Gadgets WHERE Visibility IN("Everyone", "Registered User", "Site Owner", "Accountant")
```

Coming up blank on all our searches, so would love some help on this one.

Comment: should that be single quotes?

Comment: If you have a usergroup table you can check against rows of usergroup names.

Comment: Re single quotes: probably. Sorry, was just trying to get the concept across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this may work.

```
SELECT * FROM Gadgets g WHERE exists (
select 1 from usergroup u where u.visibility = g.visibility
)
```

Comment: Yup - that will do the job. Thanks. We were thinking in a completely different direction for this one. Have used EXISTS many times. Not sure why we didn't even consider it :-)

Answer (score 3):

With a bit more digging we found [ARRAY_CONTAINS](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#array_contains), which would probably be a better answer to the original question - even though we did end up using EXISTS and referencing another table.

We thought it best to throw it in here for anyone else searching on this topic.

Comment: Can you please share the exact statement you used?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue with H2.
My use case is finding all the children in a hierarchy of one or multiple parents(filtered by user access), including the parents. So I had to check if an array contains one of multiple values.

Following my solution, I am using a subquery selecting a COUNT(*), if the count is bigger then 0 the record is a child of one of the parents:

```
SELECT *
FROM HIERARCHICAL_TABLE TOP
WHERE 0 < (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM HIERARCHICAL_TABLE SUB 
        WHERE SUB.USER_ID = 1 -- filter parents by user id
            AND (
                    TOP.ID = SUB.ID -- inculde the parents in the result
                 OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(TOP.O_PARENTS_ARRAY, SUB.ID) -- include children in result
                ) 
        )
```